# How can I force the captions to always have the same margin?

Tags: captions

I'd like all captions to have the same margins on the left and right side. How can I achieve that?

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[
labelfont=sf,
hypcap=false,
format=hang,
margin={2cm,2cm},
%also not working for forcing all captions:
%minmargin={2cm,2cm},
%maxmargin={2cm,2cm},
%justification=raggedright,
%width=0.9\columnwidth,
]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
AAA
\caption{Test.}
\end{table}
\begin{center}
BBB
\captionof{table}{Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The captions package can provide that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always better to use the built-in functionality of a class wherever possible, instead of loading extra packages.

In this case, you only need `\setcapmargin{2cm}` and `\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% built-in KOMA caption specifications
\setcapmargin{2cm}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
AAA
\captionof{table}{Test.}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
BBB
\captionof{table}{Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the `14paper` typo. Corrected the MWE shortly thereafter but you didn't catch it apparently.